# Standard Function keys using External Keyboard on 2016 Macbook Pro (touch)

Tags: keyboard, touch-bar

I recently picked up a 2016 Macbook Pro (with Touch Bar). I use an external keyboard. There used to be a setting in the keyboard system preferences that "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys". That is no longer an option. Is there a way to get that back?

Comment: Yes I find the new keyboards a step down from the old ones. I've had my new (7 month) old keyboard on my 2017 MacBook replaced last week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not apply to everyone, but in my case, I am using a Logitech Keyboard (K750). The Logitech control panel has an override to use the F-keys as standard function keys.

Answer (score 3):

At least in Sierra 10.12.3, the *Keyboard* panel of *System Preferences* has a check box for that which says:

> Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys on external keyboards
>
> When this option is selected, press the Fn key to use the special features printed on each key

Comment: In 10.12.5, it doesn't

Comment: Just checked 10.12.6 and I see the option

Comment: So weird, I just saw it there, then closed and re-opened sysprefs and it was gone. Can't seem to get it back!

Comment: This option does not appear on MacBooks with a Touchbar.

Comment: @jelder yes it does

Comment: @chrismarx I guess I photoshopped this right? https://imgur.com/a/NpvoZ2E

Comment: Is your external keyboard connected?

Comment: Contrary to comment above, I see this despite having a TouchBar

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements).

In karabiner-elements Preferences, in the Function Keys tab, there is an option at the bottom, "Use all F-keys as standard function keys"