# How to use FN keys as FN keys on macbook pro touchbar for ALL apps?

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

Touchbar breaks my external keyboard, and the option to use all fn keys as fn keys is gone. Is there a way to do so anyway? For me the whole touchbar thing is completely useless, and I'd prefer only having it while I hold the fn key, like it works when I add a single app in the settings

Sierra 10.12, 2017 model

Comment: Didn't realise you couldn't do that anymore. I don't have a Touch Bar MBP though so I can't really help.

Comment: here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262828/standard-function-keys-using-external-keyboard-on-2016-macbook-pro-touch?rq=1 they suggest to use the karabiner-elements app... doesn't it work for you?

Comment: @GioValerio I was facing issues with Karabiner - completely broken fn key. So for me it's also not the best option (as I don't have an eject key but need sleep/lock hotkey). However, it's the closest solution I see at this point

Comment: Have you tried `Touch bar shows F1, F2, etc. Keys` in Keyboard settings?

Comment: @JBallin UPD This option is only available for "Press Fn key to". I want it to be active by default.

Comment: @mr.Nutscracker, I'm referring to the setting on top. you seem to be referring to the one on the bottom. Maybe you aren't seeing it because you haven't updated your software? https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck3We.png

Comment: @JBallin yes, I don't have such option on top, are you using High Sierra? I encounter lots of bugs on it, so I won't be updating to it :(

Comment: Yes I use High Sierra

Answer (score 2):

If you go to Settings > Keyboard, in the Keyboard pane, the box "Touch Bar shows" select "F1, F2, etc. Keys" as the option.

The touch bar will now just show `Fn` keys as if it was a normal keyboard. (They will dim and appear black sometimes.)

Then, you can change the setting directly below, "Press Fn key to" and select "Expand Control Strip" or "Show App Controls". This will fulfill your request to "only have it while I hold the fn key."

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Bens answer, I found a new option which is more to my liking: I can use F1 etc as usual on my external keyboard and leave the original setting on the macbooks keyboard. This is good for me, since I use fn keys only when coding, and I only code with a proper keyboard. When I am on the road, I usually write, so it's fine to have the touchbar as it was designed.

[image: preferences]